# Ruby EventMachine and Multicast

Tags: ruby, sockets, network-programming, multicast, eventmachine

I was unable so far to find any documentation on proper multicast implementation in EventMachine.

The idea is basically to have a node register to a multicast group, send and receive group messages.

Could anyone pinpoint me to some documentation or recommendations ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented some SSDP stuff using multicast UDP and EventMachine; take a look: https://github.com/turboladen/upnp/blob/master/lib/upnp/ssdp/multicast_connection.rb

Answer (score 0):

I am using something similar to this with much success:

https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket/blob/master/examples/multicast.rb

Comment: I think the questioner is referring to UDP multicast.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
class MulticastHandler
    def receive_data( data )
        puts data
    end

    def post_init
        port, host = Socket::unpack_sockaddr_in( get_sockname() )
        ip = IPAddr.new( host ).hton + IPAddr.new("0.0.0.0").hton
        set_sock_opt( Socket::IPPROTO_IP, Socket::IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, ip )
    end
end


mcast_handler = EM::open_datagram_socket(host, port, MulticastHandler)
```